# count the number of positive integer pairs (n;m) that $5^n < 2^m < 2^{m+2} < 5^{n+1}$ and $ 1 \leq m \leq 2018$

Tags: logarithms, integers

Count the number of positive integer pairs (n;m) that $5^n < 2^m < 2^{m+2} < 5^{n+1}$ and $ 1 \leq m \leq 2018$

Using a C++ program, it is easily to get the answer is 280.

But how to do it just using math??

We have:
$$5^n < 2^m \Leftrightarrow n < m\log_52$$
and
$$2^{m+2} < 5^{n+1} \Leftrightarrow (m+2)\log_52−1<n$$
$$\Rightarrow(m+2)\log_52−1<n<m\log_52.$$

What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good so far.  The number of $n$ in that interval is $\lfloor m\log_5 2 \rfloor$ minus $\lfloor m\log_5 2 - \log_5 (5/4) \rfloor$.  This is usually zero, unless the fractional part of $m\log_5 2$ is less than $\log_5 (5/4)$, in which case it’s $1$.  So you can just count the number of $m$ in $1,2,\ldots,2018$ satisfying that inequality.

Comment: As a consistency check, since the fractional part of $m\log_5 2$ should be equidistributed in $[0,1)$, you expect the answer to be about $2018 \log_5(5/4) \approx 279.8$.  Which it is.

Comment: I dont' understand why $\{m\log_52\} < \log_5(5/4) \Rightarrow  2018\log_5(5/4)$ value

Comment: Because if $\{m \log_5 2\}$ is equally likely to have any value from $0$ to $1$, and you test $N$ arbitrary choices for $m$, then you expect it to be less than $y\in [0,1)$ approximately $N y$ times.